# Kafka console consumer not able to connect to zookeeper server on AWS EC2 server

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I have installed kafka along with zookeeper in a single AWS EC2 instance.
I have changed the hostname of the server to kafka.
When I create topic it runs fine:

```
/home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper kafka:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
Created topic "test".
```

kafka-console-producer.sh also runs fine:

```
/home/kafka/kafka/bin# /home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list kafka:9092 --topic test
[2017-10-11 20:58:13,924] WARN Property topic is not valid (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
testing
```

But the kafka producer is timing out:

```
ubuntu@kafka:~$ /home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper kafka:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 6000
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:880)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:171)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:126)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:143)
at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.create(ConsumerConnector.scala:94)
at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:145)
at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
```

Kafka, zookeeper and the broker(one) is running on the same ec2 server and they have default configuration.
Am I missing something in this installation?

Comment: The ZooKeeper port for your consumer should be 2181.

Comment: Thank you vahid, can you add that as an answer. This worked:/home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper kafka:2181 --topic test --from-beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you use the old consumer (and use the `--zookeeper` argument) the ZooKeeper port should be provided (`2181`).

However, please note that the old consumer is now deprecated, and using the new consumer is highly recommended. Please see the answer by Mickael Maison for more info.

Answer (score 2):

The new consumer (like the producer) does not connect to zookeeper anymore, it only connects to Kafka.

Replace `--zookeeper` in your command by `--bootstrap-server`:

`/home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --topic test --from-beginning`